# Finding a Polynomial Basis for a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on this question:

> Consider $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$ be all polynomials of degree at most 2 with real coefficients. Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a subspace defined by $\mathcal{S} = \{p \in \mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R}): p(0) = p(1) \}$. Let T: $\mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathcal{S}$ be a linear operator defined by T(p) = p+p'. Prove or disprove T is diagonalizable.

My approach is to use the theorem "T is diagonalizable iff its algebraic and geometric multiplicity is the same". So, I started by finding a basis of T. Since every element in $\mathcal{S}$ is in the form $ax^2-ax+b$, we have $T(ax^2-ax+b) = ax^2+(a-1)x+b$. I feel like the basis should only contain 2 elements (since it is governed by 2 variables), but besides 1, what could be the other basis?

AI give me the opinion of $\{1, x, x^2-x\}$ as a basis, but I do not know if I should trust this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @nor affirmed, there doesn't exist $\mathbf T:\mathcal S\to\mathcal S$. In case you did the general case with $\mathbf T:\mathcal P_2(\mathbf R)\to\mathcal P_2(\mathbf R)$, just for curiosity purposes, whether it'd be diagonalizable or not, you'd proceed like this:

Assuming basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$, notice
$$\mathbf T p(x)=p(x)+p'(x)=[\mathbf I+\mathbf D]p(x)$$
Then,
$$\left.\begin{align}
&\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}1=0=(0,0,0)\\
&\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}x=1=(0,0,1)\\
&\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}x^2=2x=(0,2,0)
\end{align}\right\}\implies\mathbf D\equiv
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\implies \mathbf T=\mathbf I+\mathbf D\equiv
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
$\mathbf T$'s characteristic polynomial is
$$p(\mathbf T)=(1-\lambda)^3,$$
and so, $\lambda=1$ has algebraic multiplicity $3$.

The rank of $\mathbf T-\mathbf I$ is $2$ since the determinant of $\mathbf T-\mathbf I$ is $0$ but the minor
$$\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{vmatrix}$$
isn't, which means the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda=1$ is $$\text{dim}\, \text{Nuc}(\mathbf T-\mathbf I)=\text{dim}\,\mathcal P_2(\mathbf R)-\text{dim}(\mathbf T-\mathbf I)=3-2=1$$
Since both multiplicities differ, the linear operator isn't diagonalizable by the theorem you stated.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I do not think that is correct. If $\beta = {1,x,x^2}$, then $    [T]_{\beta} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
T(1)_{\beta} &T(x)_{\beta} &T(x^2)_{\beta}
\end{bmatrix}= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 &x+1 &x^2+2x
\end{bmatrix}$, hence $[T]_{\beta}$ = $\begin{bmatrix} 
  1&1&0\\
  0&1&2\\
  0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$, then T ended up not diagonalizable since its geometric multiplicity is only 1, while algebraic multiplicity is 3.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I switched the indexes. So $(a,b,c)$ is $ax^2+bx+c$ and not $a+bx+cx^2$.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that every element in $S$ is of the form $ax^2-ax+b$ (eventually with $a=0$), and $$T(ax^2-ax+b)=ax^2+ax+b-a.$$

A basis of $S$ is given by ${\{1,x^2+x}\}$: The elements are linearly independent and span $S$. AI is wrong: $x$ is  not part of the basis, and it is even not contained in $S$.

Comment: Yes, I think it should be a $x^2+x-1$, but I get the general idea. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean that is should be a $x^2+x-1$ ? This element is not part of the basis.

Comment: I think I found out the issue. $T(ax^2-ax+b) = ax^2+ax+b-a$. In this case, it is spanned by $\{x^2+x, 1\}$. Does this sounds correct?

Comment: Yes, sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

Elements $ax^2+bx+c$ are in $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and the elements of $\mathcal{S}\subset{P}_2(\mathbb{R})  $ are not only those of the form $a(x^2-x)+b$ but **also the constant polynomials**. Cannot contain linear polynomials because $p(0)=p(1)$ and linear polynomials are injective. Then $\mathcal{S}$ cannot have the same dimension than $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However can you provide such a basis?

Comment: @Jaythelng:  A base of course  $x2−x$ and $1$ but I don't know if it is a base as you want to have (I did'nt paid attention to your problem).